# How do I use a for-each loop to remove all .php files into 0777 folders

Tags: php, bash, shell, find, xargs

The following command attempts to delete all .php files in  /  if folder permission 0777

```
find / -type f -perm 0777 -exec rm -rf *.php  \; -exec rm -rf *.html \;
```

with

```
find / -type d -perm 0777 -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf *.php
```

it's delete folder not php files

am looking to run it with terminal ssh command

i search for all folders have 0777 and remove all php files into it

Comment: HIyour question seems to be not clear. You need to change permissio of .php file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you may easily use [**`RecursiveDirectoyIterator`**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) to do this as follows :

```
$directory = 'test/';

$iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory);
$directoryIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator);

foreach ($directoryIterator as $file) {
    $octalPermission = substr(decoct($file->getPerms()), -4);
    $extension = $file->getExtension();
    if (!$file->isDir() && $octalPermission == '0777' && $extension == 'php') {
        // do some stuff
        unlink($file->getPathname());
    }
}
```

this will `recursively` iterate over your php file within a specific directory with a specific permission and delete it .

to use it for only current directory -*not recursively*- change this :

```
$iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory);
$directoryIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator);
```

by the following class :

```
$directoryIterator = new DirectoryIterator($directory);
```

---

### Update

However , as long as the OP asks to do this using terminal not php,

you may use the following command :

```
find ./test/ -type f -name "*.php" -perm 0777 | xargs rm
```

---

### Update 2 :

to checkout first for directories with permission 777 , as follows :

```
find ./test/ -type d -perm 0777 | xargs -I {} find {} -type f -name "*.php" -perm 0777 | xargs rm
```

---

### Update 3 :

to make this command applies in files with spaces/special characters , you may use the `-d` -delimiter option to set it to `\n` as follows :

```
find ./test/ -type d -perm 0777 \
| xargs -I {} find {} -type f -name "*.php" -perm 0777 \
| xargs -d '\n' rm
//      ^^^^^^^ notice this
```

this will find file name with php extension and permission 0777 then delete them.

---

### Update 4 (31 Mar 2017)

for any of the previous commands , when you try to use `xargs` command with `rm` command , if there is no files exists in your search criteria , terminal may prompt an error like following :

```
rm: missing operand
```

to avoid this , you will need to add the `-r` option to xargs :

```
-r, --no-run-if-empty        if there are no arguments, then do not run COMMAND;
```

you may use it as follows :

```
xargs -r -d '\n' rm
```

Comment: you want to execute that ssh command ? you are in php tag so i thought that you want a php way to execute your command

Comment: via a php script or your terminal ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139470/discussion-between-mikel-tawfik-and-hassan).

Comment: can i search for all folders first have 0777 and remove all php files into it ?

Comment: if file name newshell (1).php not delete get error newshell': No such file or directory

Comment: you are awesome

Comment: can i ask you to make this code to copy /.htaccess  to any folder 0777

Comment: I'm out of the town right now, maybe i will be able to answer that next saturday

Comment: thank you so much last url i fix it
looking for help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44978623/how-to-export-ssl-key-crt-and-ca-from-httpd-conf-apache-to-use-it-into-nginx-f

Comment: find /home*/*/www/ -type d -perm 0777 \
| xargs -I {} find {} -type f -name "*.php" \
| xargs -r -d '\n' rm -v     how to exclude multi folder by name