# how to export ssl key , crt and CA from httpd.conf apache to use it into nginx for all users

Tags: loops, ssh, grep, find, xargs

use custom setup that use nginx as web engine  with cpanel
need command to export ssl files to use it into nginx

cpanel now use AutoSSL powered by Comodo that give it free and will renew it automatic when any users domains ssl expire

example httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost 4xx30:4433>
  ServerName xnxxsch.com
  <IfModule ssl_module>
 SSLCertificateFile /var/cpanel/ssl/installed/certs/xnh_com_d98c5_67ca3_150707$
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/cpanel/ssl/installed/keys/d98c5_67ca3_76c14a301e0260891bbe91504$
    SSLCACertificateFile /var/cpanel/ssl/installed/cabundles/cPanel_Inc__681917bfb43af6b642178$
  </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 46.xx30:4433>
  ServerName xxxh.com
  <IfModule ssl_module>
 SSLCertificateFile /var/cpanel/ssl/installed/certs/xnah_com_d98c5_67ca3_150707$
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/cpanel/ssl/installed/keys/d98c5_67ca3_76c14a301e0260891bbe91504$
    SSLCACertificateFile /var/cpanel/ssl/installed/cabundles/cPanel_Inc__681917bfb43af6b642178$
  </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

need to export every domains  **(ServerName)**

as two files

SSLCertificateKeyFile **as** ServerName.key

and

SSLCertificateFile+ SSLCACertificateFile  **as** ServerName.crt

from ssh

with

```
grep 'ServerName' /etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

i export all need to use at loop

to get SSLCertificateKeyFile under it

and copy it with name servername.crt  to /etc/nginx/ssl/

Comment: how , i need to program script help nginx to work with ssl of cpanel

Comment: Do you want SSLCertificateFile and SSLCACertificateFile together in one file?

Comment: yes Please i was use cat SSLCertificateFile SSLCACertificateFile >> new.crt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure some efficiency nuts will choke on this, but it should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Look for ServerName, and extract the value.  Loop over results.
for server in $( grep ServerName httpd.conf | sed 's/.*ServerName\s*//' ); do
    echo $server
    # Pull out the block of XML for that server
    block=$( grep -A5 "$server" httpd.conf)

    # Extract file names from the XML block
    SSLCertificateFile=$( echo "$block" | sed -n 's/.*SSLCertificateFile\s*//p')
    SSLCertificateKeyFile=$( echo "$block" | sed -n 's/.*SSLCertificateKeyFile\s*//p')
    SSLCACertificateFile=$( echo "$block" | sed -n 's/.*SSLCACertificateFile\s*//p')

    # Create files
    cp "$SSLCertificateKeyFile" "${server}.key"
    cat "$SSLCertificateFile" "$SSLCACertificateFile" > "${server}.crt"
done
# end of loop
```

Comment: if set if [ -n "$SSLCertificateKeyFile" ]; then  before  Create files becouse not all ServerName have files

Comment: i set file with cat name 1s  has only empty enter because codes must be under others

Comment: only one problem left if server name have dash like (domain-us.com) his files not select

Comment: I just changed xnxxsch.com to xnxx-sch.com, and it still worked fine.

Comment: can i send you my file httpd.conf to test it ?

Comment: Sure.  Do you have my email address?

Comment: am afraid no i have not

Comment: Send to narceleb@gmail.com.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148701/discussion-between-mikel-tawfik-and-jack).

Comment: can you help me with update https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67739727/how-to-export-cab-crt-key-from-uapi-command-result